# Generic way of using content_tag for multiple elements of the same kind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate html like,

```
<label for='field'>
  Label Text
  <span class='span1'> Some Text 1 </span>
  <span class='span2'> Some Text 2 </span>
  ...
</label>
```

I want a call a helper such as,

`label_for 'field', :label => 'Label Text', :type1 => 'Some Text 1', :type2 => 'Some Text 2'`

For which I tried to do something like,

```
 content_tag(:label, opts[:label], :for => field_name) do
   ['span1', 'span2'].map { |i| 
     content_tag(:span, opts[i], :class => i) if opts[i] }.compact.joins('+').html_safe
   }
  end
```

But this does not work (of course).

['span1', 'span2'] array is fixed and the user has the option of choosing to display as many spans as needed.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
def special_label_for(field_name, label_text, span_array)
  content_tag "label", :for => field_name do
    concat label_text
    span_array.each_with_index do |span_content, index|
      concat content_tag("span", span_content, :class => "span" + index.to_s)
    end
  end
end

special_label_for :user_name, "User Name", ["This is the first Span", "And this is the second Span", "Can also have a third span", "Or as many spans as you like"]
```

Haven't tested this code, may need to add/remove the `concat` or an `html_safe` to get it rendering properly in your view.

Comment: This does not render the span elements.

Comment: @Rahul Apologies - had a typo `contant_tag` as `content_tag`. Try again?

Comment: I used content_tag. It renders the label only.

Comment: @Rahul Are you sure you copied the code exactly as above? The function should go in a helper and the bottom line should go in your view. It's working fine for me? Can you provide a gist of the exact code your using?

Comment: @Rahul This is pretty different to the code i suggested! Can you give me the line of code you're using to create the label. I'll take a look at this now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13200/discussion-between-rahul-and-rob-dapice)

Comment: input_tag_for 'email', :label => 'Email', :error_text => 'Email cannot be blank', :remote_error_text => 'Email is already taken'

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing I need mutliple html element in Label. I solved here

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/label_tag#1428-Html-inside-Lable-tag

You can pass parameters to make dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can even do something like this:

if the given array is `list_of_items`

```
list_of_items.map{ |item| content_tag(:span, item) }.join('').html_safe
```